# Trying to add some javascript to xslt file so that table can be hidden or shown

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

this is my first ever question. Sorry if it's a dumb one but I've been trying to do this all afternoon without any joy.

I have some XML that looks like this

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='style.xslt'?>
    <LogFileProcessing>
    <Test>
    <Script>
        <Name>Test 1</Name>
        <Results>
            <RunResult>
                <RunNumber>1</RunNumber>
                <Outcome>Pass</Outcome>
                <StartTime>10:42:25</StartTime>
                <EndTime>10:43:58</EndTime>
                <Date>25/03/2014</Date>
                <Duration>93 seconds</Duration>
            </RunResult>
            <RunResult>
                <RunNumber>2</RunNumber>
                <Outcome>Pass</Outcome>
                <StartTime>10:44:03</StartTime>
                <EndTime>10:45:13</EndTime>
                <Date>25/03/2014</Date>
                <Duration>70 seconds</Duration>
            </RunResult>
        </Results>
    </Script>
    <Script>
        <Name>Test 2</Name>
        <Results>
            <RunResult>
                <RunNumber>1</RunNumber>
                <Outcome>Pass</Outcome>
                <StartTime>10:45:17</StartTime>
                <EndTime>10:46:37</EndTime>
                <Date>25/03/2014</Date>
                <Duration>80 seconds</Duration>
            </RunResult>
            <RunResult>
                <RunNumber>2</RunNumber>
                <Outcome>Pass</Outcome>
                <StartTime>10:46:41</StartTime>
                <EndTime>10:47:49</EndTime>
                <Date>25/03/2014</Date>
                <Duration>68 seconds</Duration>
            </RunResult>
        </Results>
    </Script>
</Test>
```

and here is the xsl file I am using to transform it

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
        <xsl:for-each select="LogFileProcessing/Test/Script">
            <div style="font-family:Arial;background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
            <span style="font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></span>
            </div>
            <div style="font-family:Arial;margin-left:75px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
            <p>
        <table border="1">
                <tr style="color:white" bgcolor="Teal">
                <th>Run</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Pass/Fail</th>
      <th>Reason</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Results/RunResult">
    <tr>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="RunNumber"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="RunNumber"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="StartTime"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="StartTime"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="EndTime"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="EndTime"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="Duration"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="Duration"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="Outcome"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="Outcome"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="FailureReason"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><span>N/A</span></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </p>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure there are far better ways of doing the above, but what I want to do is have a link, preferably on each of the Name lines that will show or hide the table that is displayed directly beneath it.

I have tried something along the lines of [document.style.display not sticking for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832357/document-style-display-not-sticking-for-some-reason)

and

http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/55403-hiding-showing-table-html-through-xslt.html

but as a noob to the world of coding, XML, and XSL I'm a little lost. Any help would be gratefully appreciated and forward my understanding of this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 can do that without Javascript, using the `details` and the `summary` elements:

```
        <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <head>
          <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
        <xsl:for-each select="LogFileProcessing/Test/Script">
          <details>
            <summary style="font-family:Arial;background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">

            <span style="font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></span>
            </summary>
            <div style="font-family:Arial;margin-left:75px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">

        <table border="1">
                <tr style="color:white" bgcolor="Teal">
                <th>Run</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Pass/Fail</th>
      <th>Reason</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Results/RunResult">
    <tr>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="RunNumber"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="RunNumber"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="StartTime"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="StartTime"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="EndTime"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="EndTime"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="Duration"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="Duration"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="Outcome"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="Outcome"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="FailureReason"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><span>N/A</span></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </div>
  </details>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately it looks like support for those elements is in Chrome and Opera and Safari while Firefox and IE only render them but don't support the interactivity. So we need Javascript for those browsers that don't implement those elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <head>
          <title>Test</title>
          <script><![CDATA[
          function toggle(summary) {
            var details = summary.parentNode;
            if (details.nodeType === 1 && details.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'details')
            {
              if (typeof details.open === 'undefined')
              {
                var div = details.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
                if (div) {
                  div.style.display = div.style.display === '' ? 'none' : '';
                }
              }
            }
          }
          ]]></script>
          <style>details { display: block;}</style>
        </head>
        <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
        <xsl:for-each select="LogFileProcessing/Test/Script">
          <details>
            <summary style="font-family:Arial;background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px" onclick="toggle(this);">

            <span style="font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></span>
            </summary>
            <div style="font-family:Arial;margin-left:75px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">

        <table border="1">
                <tr style="color:white" bgcolor="Teal">
                <th>Run</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Pass/Fail</th>
      <th>Reason</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Results/RunResult">
    <tr>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="RunNumber"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="RunNumber"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="StartTime"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="StartTime"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="EndTime"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="EndTime"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="Duration"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="Duration"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="Outcome"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><xsl:value-of select="Outcome"/></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Outcome = 'Fail'">
          <td bgcolor="Red">
          <xsl:value-of select="FailureReason"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td bgcolor="White"><span>N/A</span></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </div>
  </details>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
```

See http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014032503.xml for an example.

Comment: Thank you Martin, the Javascript one worked perfectly. The HTML5 one didn't though. I'll look at both and try to understand them so I can replicate in future. Thanks again.

Comment: Which browsers did you try for the HTML5 suggestion? As I said, it looks like only Chrome, Safari and Opera support that stuff: http://caniuse.com/details.